# Python: printing ascii art from text file, backslashes are being doubled

Tags: python, text, ascii-art

I made some ascii art in notepad, saved it as a .txt file, and then I used rsync to throw it on a remote server. I wrote a simple python script in the same directory to just echo the contents of the file, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
with open('ascii_art.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
f.close()
```

Here's my problem: every time the script encounters a '\' character (which is just part of the ascii art), it prints it twice.

I get that the backslash is an escape character in python, but I don't understand how to get it to not do this. I tried changing one of the backslashes in the text file to a double backslash, thinking it might undo it, but it gave me 4 backslashes instead.

On top of that, at the end of every line in the ascii txt file, the script actually prints out '\r\n' . I'm not sure how to get rid of those.

Anyone have any thoughts on this? Thanks

Comment: Do you have to read it as a binary? Why can't you do `with open("ascii_art.txt", 'r') as f:` that should work fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it might be because of the file mode being `rb` instead of `r` but it's really a guess until you post the actual `ascii_art.txt`:

```
with open('ascii_art.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: I accepted it, sorry about the delay! It wouldn't let me "accept" for 10 more minutes after you answered and I forgot to come back and do it. Thanks for the help!